# Rails 3, Polymorphic Associations, and No Route Matches

Tags: polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been learning Rails for about 6 weeks now, so still a noob!

I'm following Ryan Bates screencast on Polymorphic Associations, but I'm getting a "No Route Matches" error when navigating to /model/xx/comments.

After two days going round in circles with this I'm totally stumped—everything appears to be in place.

Comments model:

```
create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
t.text     "content"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "commentable_id"
t.string   "commentable_type"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comments class:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true 
end
```

Other models class:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable 
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :modelname, :has_many => :comments
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def index
@commentable = find_commentable  
@comments = @commentable.comments
end

private

  def find_commentable 
    params.each do |name, value|  
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
            return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
        end  
    end  
    nil  
  end
```

This all according to the tutorial, but nonetheless is returning "no route matches".

I have tried alternative formatting of the routes as nested resources.

```
resources :modelname do |modelname|
  modelname.resources :comments
end
```

Explicitly defining comments in routes.rb

```
resources :comments
```

And various combinations of terms in routes.rb

```
resources :modelname, :has_many => :commentables
```

or

```
resources :modelname, :has_many => :comments
```

or

```
resources :modelname, :has_many => :comments, :through => :commentable
```

all without success.

Has anyone else encountered this? I'm lost as to where to begin looking.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3, routing is done differently. You specify relationships in the model and map your routes in routes.rb

In the Rails 3 way of doing things, your routes.rb you should have this:

```
 resources :model do
    resources :comments
 end
```

You should not be specifying your relationships in routes. Refresh your server and you should get a route like /model/id/comments/id

Comment: Thank you for putting me out of my misery. Simple, but effective!

Comment: I would also like to add that I added a nested route and had the same problem.  Then, I rebooted the server and it started working.  So basically, adding nested routes on a running server doesn't always work.  :-)  Reboot it.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3, things are a bit different. To get the URL `modelname/id/comments`, you'll want the following route in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :modelname do
  resources :comments
end
```

See [this Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for more, it goes it to a lot more detail.

Comment: Easy when you know how! Thanks for the pointer and the useful link, worked like a charm.

Comment: Haha, that's the way it always works, huh? Glad to have helped.